# textarea fields: IE behaves differently when loaded through a partial refresh

Tags: html, ajax, internet-explorer, xpages

I have a page in XPages that I use to open and edit a document. There are two ways to open a document in edit-mode: first in read-mode then click a button to put it in edit-mode, or open it directly in edit-mode. Both work in all browsers, yet IE seems to handle both cases differently. We found this out when working with the SWING API.

Opening directly in edit-mode in IE (8/9/10) works, via read-mode to edit-mode doesn't. What we found is that the internal representation of a textarea field differs: when opened in edit-mode, there are more properties, but most importantly, the return+linefeeds are correctly set in both the value and the innerText property.

The button just contains a simple Change Mode action.

Has anyone heard of this anomaly? And does someone know what we did wrong?

PS I'll try to build a simple XPage that shows this behaviour more clearly tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IE switching from read to edit mode, you need a full page refresh

Comment: Thanks. Which immediately leads to the next question: why??
(A: because it doesn't work. Q: why doesn't it work? A: IE sucks)

Comment: It all boils down to how a browser deals with DOM manipulations. In a partial refresh, parts of the DOM are replaced with a server response. Different browsers behave differently. You could check using a http debugger what's coming over the wire to gain an insight.

Comment: Anyway, you don't really need a full page refresh in all cases. Usually, everything works, except in our case. I still haven't found or made the time to create the example XPage I mentioned...